# Can the author control Amazon excerpts or are they automatically generated?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing

Amazon books frequently feature excerpts available to readers via a "Look Inside!" feature on the Amazon site for books.

Can the author of a book (or publisher) control what parts of the book are made available for preview or does Amazon automatically extract and generate these excerpts?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has an algorithm which pulls the first number of pages for display (a percentage of the total).

Here are the real details which show you how to request it to be set up and how to request that Look Inside is turned off for your book:

https://authorcentral.amazon.com/gp/help?ie=UTF8&topicID=200407430

This all works for printed books (via CreateSpace) and ebooks via Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to bypass the system, but the default is for the first pages of the book to be the ones that show up on the Look Inside pages.